# How can you run a sentAction and a Push on one button using storyboard?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

I have a button I've added to a UIToolBar that takes me to the next viewcontroller in my storyboard. I normally switch between UIViewControllers by ctrl-clicking the button and dragging it to the viewcontroller I want to use. Now, I'd like to:

1. Run a method
2. Push to the next viewcontroller

I figured I could do this in code, but the following code just crashes:

`AddCharacterD20ViewController *AddD20ViewController = [[AddCharacterD20ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddCharacterD20ViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:AddD20ViewController animated:YES];`

Here is the exception:
[AddCharacterD20ViewController_Intro Next]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa56c4a0'

Anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Create a segue in the storyboard, by dragging from your view controller (NOT from the button).

2) Give it an identifier

3) add the following code:

```
- (IBAction)onClickMethod:(id)sender 
{
    // replace "SegueIdentifier" with the segue identifier string from the storyboard
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueIdentifier" sender:self];
}
```

(make sure the action is connected to the button on the storyboard.)

4) Profit! :)

Comment: If I could vote something up nine times, I would. Thanks, BlackRider.